# Subtracting added number from .txt characters doesn't reverse encryption?

Tags: c, encryption

When encrypting a text file and then running the algorithm with "byte-key" to undo the encryption, it just changes the jumbled text and doesn't actually reverse anything. Is there some concept I'm missing?

```
void encrypt(char filePath[],int key) {
    FILE * file;
    char byte;
    file = fopen(filePath,"r+");
    while( (byte = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        fputc(byte+key,file);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: You can't read and write to the file like that. When you read, the file position is advanced. So when you write, you're overwriting the next character. Try opening two files. Read from one, and write to the other.

Comment: In theory, you could also use `fseek` to move the file position back to overwrite the byte you read. I say "in theory" because you may or may not also need to be aware of buffering, which would require flushing the output before doing the next read. I'm not sure it's necessary in this case, but would be good to read up on that if you encounter unusual behavior in your program.

Comment: Although I suppose you could `fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR);` before `fputc()`. *In update mode ('+'), both input and output may be performed, but output cannot be followed by input without an intervening call to fflush, fseek, fsetpos or rewind, and input cannot be followed by output without an intervening call to fseek, fsetpos or rewind, unless the input operation encountered end of file. In update mode, implementations are permitted to use binary mode even when text mode is specified.*

Comment: Use `int`, not `char byte;`  Open a separate destination file in binary mode.

Comment: @Byte: you need to seek as you switch between read and write (and as you switch between write and read), but there's no direct need to worry about buffering.  For performance reasons (if no other), you'd do better reading big chunks of file, revising them, and then writing them back, but the buffering actually copes remarkably well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how my new encrypt function looks

```
void encrypt(char filePath[],int key) {
    FILE * fileR;
    FILE * fileW;
    char dest[500],src[4];
    int byte;
    fileR = fopen(filePath,"r");
    //Combines filePath with ext for unique filename
    strcpy(dest,filePath);
    strcpy(src,ext);
    fileW = fopen(strcat(dest,src),"w");
    while( (byte = fgetc(fileR)) != EOF) {
        fputc(byte+key,fileW);
    }
    fclose(fileR);
    fclose(fileW);
}
```

It works as intended now.